# Install cordova-plugin-firebase

Tags: cordova, firebase

I'm trying to install the firebase plugin for Ionic, but running the command is the process like this, without advancing, it does not do anything.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase --save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for understanding you entered:

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase`

and it should be:

```
 `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase --save`
```

i tried and all worked fine with the last line for installing the plugin.

Comment: I've tried it now and it worked, the thing is that before I had to do an installation of a previous version, specifically the `@0.1.25` that I do not know if it will be the last one.